# How to add Alter and Select together in a query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like:

```
q="""
SELECT tb1.id, tb2.time
FROM table1 tb1
   LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.pid=tb1.pid
ALTER TABLE tb2 ADD INDEX my_col (`my_col` ASC)
ORDER BY tb1.time DESC;
"""
```

I just found that to improve my query efficiency I need MySQL EXPLAIN. Then using workbench I realized to add a index to improve a part of query, however when I try to add this alter index to original query gives me syntax error. Do you know how can I implement EXPLAIN points like indexing to a query?

Comment: You cannot do a `Alter` and `Select` together. `Alter` is a one time change; it is a DDL query, and you fire it once to add indexes to your table. Afterwards, you can fire your `SELECT` query individually as many times as required. So, just execute: `ALTER TABLE tb2 ADD INDEX my_col` first, and remove it from your select query to run the select query later as required.

Comment: Since I want to run the above query for multiple databases, is it possible to make a loop and indicate for each db if index `my_col` does not exit, run first ALTER this index and then SELECT ?

Comment: I am running it in a python script

Comment: That is not how things are done. Instead, whenever you come across a slow query, add index manually. `ALTER..` statements are risky if left alone.

Comment: Totally clear now. I appreciate your answer.